# jQuery: Position a div to fill the visible portion of a container div with overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning

I'm having trouble getting an overlay to appear on top of the visible portion of another div. The problem is, the container div has overflow, and if the user has scrolled inside that div, the overlay will not cover the scrolled portion. My question is: how can you position a div to fill the visible portion of another div using jQuery - or, alternatively, is there a way to accomplish this using just CSS?

[Here is a jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/burlesona/p6k2Z/), and here's the markup:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>Overflow content here</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.container { position: absolute; height: 100px; width: 100px; overflow-y: auto; }
div.overlay { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: #F00; opacity: 0.5; }
div.content p { margin-bottom: 100px; }
```

and JS (load on DOM Ready)

```
$('div.container').click(function(){
    $('div.overlay').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you were asking for I did the following

**CSS**

```
.container {
    /* setting this to relative means 
       overlay is positioned relative to its parent */
    position: relative; 
}
.overlay {
    /* element taken out of normal flow */
    position: absolute;
    /* removed bottom and right properties otherwise
       updating top property has no effect */
    height: 100px;
    /* When scrollbar appears width decreases to less than
       100px hence having to set to 100% to allow automatic calculation */
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

Using jQuery I now set the top property appropriately

```
$(".container").scroll( function( ) {
    $(".overlay").css({ top: $(this).scrollTop( ) });
});
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p6k2Z/2/)

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately the real-world container I'm dealing with is part of a fluid layout and has to be positioned absolute. The container markup and CSS is pretty much stuck as I've shown it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM property `scrollHeight` :

```
$('div.container').click(function(){
    $('div.overlay').css("height", this.scrollHeight).toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6k2Z/1/

---

**EDIT :**

In order to just overlay the visible portion, you can use this :

```
$('div.container').click(function(){
    $('div.overlay').css({
        top: this.scrollTop,
        height: $('div.container').css("height")})
    .toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6k2Z/3/

Comment: That fills up the entire div though, I think he just wants to fill the visible part.

Comment: Hum, yes, I was not really sure, too : but as all was covered (except the scrollbar, but I think that this is not the problem)...

Comment: I would prefer to have the overlay exactly covering the visible portion, but this is a good fallback strategy. I'll leave the question open for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew what are you calling the visible portion? Is it with the scrollbar?

Comment: No, the scrollbar doesn't need to be covered. What I mean is the currently visible content area of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really want to cover only the visible portion:

http://jsfiddle.net/GNCaT/1/

```
<style type="text/css">
div.overlay { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    height:100px; /* fixed height, set by CSS or javascript, no bottom */
    background: #F00; 
    opacity: 0.5; 
}
</style>

<script>
$('div.container').click(function(){
    $('div.overlay').css('top', $('div.container').scrollTop() + 'px').toggle();
});​
</script>
```

This will position the overlay to the top of the visible portion of the container.